# Is there any wordpress plugin available to auto share comments?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, comments

I'm trying to achieve like this. See the image.

[image]

Is there any good free or premium plugin available to add this feature?
I know there are some plugins out there like janrain,gigya. But those plugins have limits in free version. Their fee also high. So i don't like their plugin. Any other good plugin available?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the JetPack Plugin from WordPress.com

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jetpack/

Comment: I think jetpack doesn't have that feature. Check [this page](http://jetpack.me/)

Comment: Look at the ShareDaddy section of that page.

Comment: I'm not seeing any option to auto share. If you are referring to just share button then please understand there are lot of plugins like sharethis,addthis availabe in wordpress directory. Here i'm asking an auto share plugin. I mean if the user checked those checkboxes then that comment should be  shared to respective social sites SIMULTANEOUSLY. For more information click any post in huffingtonpost.com and goto comment section. You will understand what i mean.